# Adding conditional statements to engine

Tags: php

I am trying to add the ability to use conditional statements to this basic engine I am trying to develop and I cannot figure out why it will not work. Can anyone help? It is not replacing the text.

here is the `template.php` for the conditional statements

```
<?php

class Template {
    private $vars = array();

    public function assign($key, $value) {
        $this->vars[$key] = $value;
    }

    public function render($file_name) {
        $path = $file_name . '.html';

        if (file_exists($path)) {

            $content = file_get_contents($path);

            foreach ($this->vars as $key => $value) {
                $content = preg_replace('/\{' . $key . '\}/', $value, $content);
            }

            $content = preg_replace('/\{if (.*)\}/', '<?php if ($1): ?>', $content);
            $content = preg_replace('/\{elseif (.*)\}/', '<?php elseif ($1): ?>', $content);
            $content = preg_replace('/\{else\}/', '<?php else: ?>', $content);
            $content = preg_replace('/\{\/if\}/', '<?php endif; ?>', $content);

            eval(' ?>' . $content . '<?php ');

        } else {
            exit('<h4>Engine error...</h4>');
        }
    }
}

?>
```

and here is the implementation in the html

```
<div class="container">
            <div id="content">
                <h3>{pagetitle}</h3>
                <hr />
                <span>My name is {username} and I am {age} years old</span>

                {if ({age}==21)}
                    21
                {elseif ({age}==22)}
                    22
                {else}
                    none
                {/if}

           </div>
</div>
```

it literally prints out the conditional block above as you see it inline

Comment: Why is that so hard to use some existent template engine or use just PHP?

Comment: @George Cummins it literally prints out the `{if}`...to `{/if}`

Comment: @I Am Not Procrastinating I just wanted to try and make one thats all

Comment: @zachstarnes - are your preg_replace statements working? Echo out the content after each one, and make sure they're replacing the text in the way you expect.

Comment: Well... http://www.codediesel.com/php/building-a-simple-parser-and-lexer-in-php/

Comment: @andrewsi i tried echoing out the $content variable and it does not print anything its just a blank screen

Comment: Your including <?php and ?> inside of strings ($content). It can not be good in any way... What's your intention with that?

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld it would like `{if (...)}` to be replaced with `<?php if (...): ?>` but it wont

Comment: Your result is {if ({age}==21)} but what is your desired result then?

Comment: I don't think!? you could do conditional statements inside of a string like the way you are doing? (without maybe using eval). Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld in the comments below is how I fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess that you would need to make all of your regex patterns ungreedy.

Doing something like this:

```
/\{if (.*)\}/
```

will replace the everything between the first instance of `{if` and the last instance of `}` with your replacement.  Make the match ungreedy by using `U` flag in the pattern like this:

```
/\{if (.*)\}/U
```

Comment: Thought about that already. But wouldn't there be atleast an `<?php if(...): ?>` in the `$content` after parsing?

Comment: @Lukas that is what I thought, for some reason it will not work.

Comment: @Mike Brant that worked but i had to place the result in a tag for it to appear

Comment: @Mike Brant do you know why it does not replace it with `<?php if(): ?>`

Comment: @Lukas Potentially not, there could be a  key/value replacement, since those are done first. I am just seeing the content about blank screen, which might leave me to believe the problem is actually in reading the file, or there might be some other fatal error.

Comment: @zachstarnes I am not sure what you mean by you have to place it in a tag for it to appear.  You had to place what in a tag?  Also for your second comment why doe WHAT not get replace with `<?php if(): ?>`?

Comment: @Mike Brant if i changed the syntax to make it `{(if)}` instead of `{if}` then i was able to remove the `U`

Comment: @zachstarnes Change the syntax where? In your regex? In the template?

Comment: @Mike Brant in the template.php i changed the `/\{if (.*)\}/` to `/\{\(if (.*)\)\}/` so instead of typing `{if (...)}` in the html you type `{(if (...))}` doing so abled me to remove the `U` im assuming because it does not match the `{var}` syntax anymore

Comment: @zachstarnes No it is actually because, by introducing the parenthesis as part of the pattern, the matching logic changes.  Personally, I would use the ungreedy match, as it is more clear as to your intent.